# Find a child value using value event listener inside the value event listener of another child of the same firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database in firebase.

[image: Database model image]

I'm getting a null pointer reference and I'm not really sure I'm doing it the right way.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

I get a message from the snapshot of the child "Messages", get the receiver and sender ID, use those IDs and search the snapshot of the child "Users".
Then I want to store the other receiver user (if this user sent him a message) or this user (if some other user sent this user a message) in an arraylist of custom type 'UserData'. In between I am also checking the array list for duplicate values. I am using that array list later with an adapter. Here's the code.

```
public ArrayList<UserData> makeChatDialogListForAdapter() {

    chatDialogList = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference messagesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages");
    messagesDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot !=null) {
                String currentUserId = grabUserIdFromUserDetails(currentUser.getDisplayName(), currentUser.getEmail());
                final Message generalMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                if (generalMessage.getReceiverUserId().equals(currentUserId))   //someone sent a message to current user
                {
                    DatabaseReference userDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                    userDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            UserData chatUser = dataSnapshot.child(generalMessage.getSenderUserId()).getValue(UserData.class);
                            if (!chatDialogList.contains(chatUser))
                                chatDialogList.add(chatUser);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                } else if (generalMessage.getSenderUserId().equals(currentUserId))  //current user sent message to someone
                {
                    DatabaseReference userDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                    userDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            UserData chatUser = dataSnapshot.child(generalMessage.getReceiverUserId()).getValue(UserData.class);
                            if (!chatDialogList.contains(chatUser))
                                chatDialogList.add(chatUser);
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return chatDialogList;
}
```

Here is the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This check is not needed: `if(dataSnapshot !=null) {`. A `DataSnapshot` will never be null. Even if there's not data at the location, the `DataSnapshot` will be a valid object. To check whether any data exists at the location, use [`DataSnapshot.exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#exists()).

Comment: Thanks but I put it there because I was trying literally anything hoping to fix it. Things are the same even when I remove it. Any more help please?

Comment: I know it doesn't hurt, which is why I left it as a comment. But please post the **minimal** code that reproduces the problem in the future. Anything additional is just a distraction.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind in future. Also, say I want to get the userId from /Users in the same database using parameters displayName and email (I'm getting them using firebase auth ). I'm using this function (https://imgur.com/a/xNwYVZ8) but i'm getting a null id. Could you please take a look at it ? I guess a day ago it worked.

Comment: Let's stick to one question at a time. If you have another problem after this one is solved, post a new question for that problem with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching a `ValueEventListener` to `/Messages`. Since there are multiple messages under there, the `DataSnapshot` that is passed into `onDataChange` will contain multiple child nodes. Your handler doesn't handle the fact that it receives multiple messages:

```
messagesDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Sytem.out.println(messageSnapshot.getKey());  // 01, 02, etc
            Sytem.out.println(messageSnapshot.child("messageText").getValue(String.class));  // "Hello, how are you?", etc
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: This particular thing works thanks. But what I specifically need doesn't. There's still the null pointer error when I'm creating a new Message.class object inside my onDataChange. And I can't seem to find the cause.